# Storing data in HTML tags as custom attributes

Tags: html, template-tal, zpt

Is it a good practice storing related information in the `HTML` tag?

```js
$("#my_div").append("<span id='info' boo='foo'/>");
$("#info").attr("boo");
```

I've encountered with such technique (and slightly borrowed it) in `TAL` (in `ZPT`) where you could use `tal:attributes` statement to modify `HTML` tags (e.g. passing the value of `boo` variable from backend to be rendered in the final document as attribute value):

```xml
<span id='info' tal:attributes='boo view/boo'>
```

result:

```html
<span id='info' boo='foo'>
```

Will this technique break a document someday, or it is safe by the spec?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The right way to do it is to use data-* attributes:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Tangentially, jQuery has a special method for working with these as well. For example:

```
<p id='string' data-user_name='thedude'></p>
$('#string').data('user_name') => "thedude"
typeof $('#string').data('name') => "string"

<p id='number' data-user_id='12345'</p>
typeof $('#number').data('user_id') => "number"

<p id='boolean' data-user_is_active='true'></p>
typeof $('#boolean').data('user_is_active') => "boolean"

<p id = 'json' data-user='{"name": "the dude", "id": "12345"}'></p>
typeof $('#json').data('user') => "object"
// embedding JSON is extremely useful in my experience
```

Comment: "It would be inappropriate, however, for the user to use generic software not associated with that music site to search for tracks of a certain length by looking at this data. 
This is because these attributes are intended for use by the site's own scripts, and are not a generic extension mechanism for publicly-usable metadata."

What? Is that W3C telling me what to do and what not to do as a free web user?

Answer (score 1):

[w3.org](http://www.w3.org) allows in HTML5 to use user custom data in html tags;

See the section:

[**3.2.3.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen [...]

Example:

```
<ol>
 <li data-length="2m11s">Beyond The Sea</li>
 ...
</ol>
```

So, I'll say that it is a accepted practice for HTML5.

Comment: The risks of that technique will break a document are lower. You may have problems with older versions of HTML or browsers, but provably not in the future. In my opinion, this practice allows better semantic information for data managing transparent for the user. With this in mind.. I think w3c will extend the practice rather than ban it.